# Read and Write Image file inside web-app in grails

Tags: java, grails

I am reading an image from web-app/images and creating a duplicate of same in same location with different name. A Grails Application.

I am getting the real path of the file using the follwing code,

```
    def serveletContext = ServletContextHolder.servletContext
    def filePath = serveletContext.getRealPath( "web-app/images" )
    def actFile= new File(filePath+ "myimg.png")
    final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(actFile)
```

This is working fine in my devlopment environment. Both read and write happening fine.
 When I am deploying WAR of the application in Tomcat i'm getting the exception

> java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException    at
>   BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:39)   at
>   grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
>     at
>   grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
>     at
>   grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!

Please tell me how to resolve this. Or I can do the same by using relative path instead real path in anyway?

Comment: have u checked any permission related issues? if server is linux?

Answer (score 0):

If you tested it on local and if is working. It might be due to server issue related to permission setting.

Please check the the permission on the tomcat **webapps** directory at least make sure it read and writeable to 755.

`chmod u+x / 755 webapps`

if not please add more code , to inspect your bug ,,, if you have used any other plugin also?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need to deploy as a unpacked war otherwise getRealPath returns null on Tomcat.  Under conf directory look at server.xml for unpackWARs attribute.

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">
```